# Missing spaces when using overleaf

Tags: spacing, overleaf, italic, missing

I'm using overleaf to write my thesis, after using the \textit{} command, the following text is still in italic and the spaces between words are missing.

Is this a common problem and what can I do about it?

[image]

The potential evaporation rate \textit{h_{v_p(j)}} [\textit{mm}] was estimated by a simplified approach based on a modified evaporation equation \eqref{eq:evap_br} by Brandt.

Thats the code I used.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome in this community. You not can use commands for text with the mix of a formula. It is necessary to use $... $. And textit in math mode is mathit. However in math mode you will have italic mode.

Comment: Never ignore errors, You will have a red error number in overleaf and an error about missing math delimiter. After any error don't even look at the pdf output except as possible debugging aid.

Comment: `$h_{v_{p(j)}}[mm]$`